# How to reset Kendo dropdownlist which is dynamically binded to property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I require to bind a Kendo dropdownlist dynamically.

The following is my code:

```
dropdown1.selected(0);
dropdown.Value(0);
```

But it doesn't work. Please suggest.

Comment: Go to Kendo UI forums: http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-web

Answer (score 0):

First you have to access the Dropdownlist,

```
var dropdownlist = $('#DropdownlistID').data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Then using the Value(string value_to_be_displayed) function,

```
dropdownlist.value("Oranges");
```

Be reminded, the value is not used with the index of dropdownlist item. It only accepts string and displays string.